# Any downside of running multiple hosted service within a .Net Core Windows Service?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-3.1

Currently, we have a .Net Framework 4.7 based windows service that we install through MSI built using Wix. But during install, we register multiple windows services for the same exe with difference being in the arguments passed to each service. It would look like Myapp.exe -instance 1, Myapp.exe -instance 2..and so on. Each instance uses a different configuration based on the instance number and will poll different IBM MQ and process messages. We install around 14 such instances.

Now that we are looking to migrate to .Net Core, we are wondering, if its worth changing this deployment model and instead move to using multiple instances of hosted services. With this, we will simply register the hosted service multiple times but with different constructor parameter. So I am trying to understand, what could be potential downside of this approach. Till now, I could think of coupe of them.

1. Since these runs as independent processes, we currently have ability to stop/start specific instance of windows service. So we will potentially lose that ability.
2. Since these runs as independent processes, we can easily identify memory spike in a specific instance of windows service. So for troubleshooting, we can just focus on specific instance. With single executable, we lose this ability as well.

Apart from these, what other potential pitfalls that I may come across with this approach?

Also for the above 2 points, is there any workaround when using multiple hosted services?

Comment: Why do you need to keep different workers inside one executable binary? I would split them into different exe files that use shared libraries.

Comment: These are configuration driven processes. So logic is same across all instances. Based on the config, the MQ the process poll's, type of message that they process are different. So there is no point in creating separate binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure specifically about Windows Services but I had the same question for microservices. I think in general, there isn't much either way but some things to consider:

1. All services go down if you need to deploy a new one (but if they are all the same, you are more likely to update all of them at the same time)
2. Coordinating between them (if necessary) might be easier (locks, transactions etc) if they are together but likewise might allow you to do things that break encapsulation because you can
3. They would all start and stop at the same time in a single service, if you want to control them separately, you will either need an external enable-disable mechanism or separate windows services.
4. If you will ever need to separate them e.g. onto separate machines, you will have to do the risky work of separating them later.

It sounds like they are largely identical just targetting different data so there aren't any things I can think of that would be a problem.